# get utxo at a certain chain height

Tags: utxo, bitcoin-cli, height, utxo-set

I have the reference client running with a complete transaction index. 
Is it possible to get all UTXO for a certain height of the chain either via `bitcoin-cli` or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

The utxo set is indexed by `transaction_id + out_index` from Bitcoin Core 0.15 onwards (just by `transaction_id` from 0.8 - 0.14). So in order to get all UTXOs for a certain height you need to parse the whole set and filter it by height.

There's no way of doing so with `bitcoin-cli` AFAIK. You can do it by using [STATUS](https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools/tree/master/bitcoin_tools/analysis/status) (a tool I'm coauthor of). Feel free to ask for support if needed.

Comment: I took a look at it, you parse the ".bitcoin/chainstate" directory, does this contain all outputs or just the utxo at current chain height?

Comment: Contains all the utxos at the height the chainstate is updated to.

Comment: is it possible then to get the utxo at an earlier chainstate?

Comment: You can work it around by re-downloading the blockchain and stop the sync process at the block height you'd like to analyze. We have a script designed for this as part of the dev brach at https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools/blob/dev/bitcoin_tools/analysis/status/kill_at_heigh.py